# Calculus II Series Properties

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right)$ the same as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\cos\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$?

I know both separately diverge based on the divergence test. But when subtracted they equal 0, does that mean divergence it is inconclusive?

Comment: This is known as "conditionally convergent". http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConditionalConvergence.html

Comment: Also, when subtracted, they do not equal zero. The sum on the left converges to $$\cos 1 - \cos 0$$

Comment: S_n = (cos 1 - cos 1/2 )+ (cos 1/2 - cos 1/3)....(...- cos 1/(n+1)).

Comment: I meant when the limits are subtracted when using the divergence test the result is 0 InterstellarProbe.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

The series can be viewed as a limit,

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N(\cos(1/n)-\cos(1/(n+1))=\lim_{N\to \infty}(\cos(1)-\cos(1/(N+1))=\cos(1)-1 \,\, .$$

Comment: This kind of series are called telescopic series